# fetchone vs fetchmany

Tags: python, sql

```
for date in c.fetchone():
    [('date')]
    print date
```

The above prints:

```
02/28/2017
```

---

```
for date in c.fetchmany(2):
    [('date')]
    print date
```

The above prints:

```
(u'02/27/2017',)  
(u'02/27/2017',)
```

Not sure why it returns the values u'xxx,) because it now prints it as a table?

Anyway, i'd like to save both values (rows) in two different variables to eventually compare them with other variables.

```
for date in c.fetchmany(2):
    [('date')]
    print date
    for row in date:
        print row[0], row[1]
```

The above will result into:

```
(u'02/27/2017',)
0 2
(u'02/27/2017',)
0 2
```

But I would expect it to print:

```
(u'02/27/2017',)
02/27/2017
(u'02/27/2017',)
02/27/2017
```

---

```
for date in c.fetchmany(2):
    [('date')]
    print date
    for row in date:
        print row[0]

(u'02/27/2017',)
0
(u'02/27/2017',)
0
```

Not sure how to solve this. Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you doing `[('date')]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just grab the first element of each tuple like this:

```
for date in c.fetchmany(2):
    [('date')]
    print date[0]
```

Comment: Thanks @wpercy, that solves my problem, however, this value requires to be assigned in two different variables date1, date2 for me to compare those with other variables.

To answer you curiosity :-) I thought I had to assign a avarialbe to whatever is returned from the fetchmany. But you are right that is not the case. Amended the code, thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear:
for date in c.fetchmany(2):
    print date[0]

prints:
02/27/2017
02/27/2017